# Need Help on Cooking Thick Pork Chops to Temperature

Tags: cooking-time, sauteing, pork-chops

Recently I attempted once again to pan-saute bone-in pork chops.
I have a recipe which calls for 1" thick such chops.
I had a choice between selecting 1/3", or 1.5" chops.
I chose the 1.5" ones.

The recipe calls for sauteing on each side for 3 minutes, turning only once.
I waited about 4 minutes before the turn, and cooked for another 2 mins before using a meat thermometer.  To say it was nowhere near the safe zone for pork is an understatement.

I cooked them for what seemed like a half-hour.

Given the time and temp, does this sounds like appropriate cooking instructions for sauteing pork chops?  With the chops being as thick as they were, should I have chosen another cooking method?

To answer what may be a follow-up question, I've never cooked chops well.  Pork loin I can do OK, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost there! Yes, start with a good hot pan and get a good sear. You might even want to get the sides, render some of that fat. Incidentally, the biggest mistake most people make when searing chops is to move them too soon. Give them at least 3 minutes before you sneak in to check the color. Get them good and brown.

For chops an inch or less thick, that might be enough after resting if you're OK with medium to medium-rare (and you really should be). More than an inch thick? You're going to need some oven time after browning, 350F for 20-40 minutes. Aim for 140F internal temperature before resting. Ideally, you should be able estimate by feel before you go poking around with a sharp thermometer, but that kind of comes with experience. When in doubt, poke with a sharp thermometer.

When you've reached 140F, allow to rest for 7-9 minutes before serving. That will bring them up to 145F.

Finally, consider brining. This is a good recipe for the brine, and a great basic recipe for thick pork chops.[Thick Pork Chops by Tyler Florence](http://www.foodnetwork.com/recipes/tyler-florence/thick-pork-chops-with-spiced-apples-and-raisins-recipe.html).